# How to save options?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have made a option's page where where we can choose fire to auto or manual...

now when i choose the option i want it to remain the same whenever i play the game until i change it again .

How?will it be saved somewhere automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for NSUserDefaults. it is perfect for something like this.

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (standardUserDefaults) {
    [standardUserDefaults setBOOL:YES forKey:@"autoFire"];
    [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Essentially, you save a BOOL into your phone, under the string 'autoFire', allowing you to obtain it by calling boolForKey:@"autoFire"